# Vagrant ssh using username and password

Tags: vagrant

I want to connect with a vagrant machine with different user instead of Vagrant also want to use another username and password instead of using keys. Also, I want to know is it possible to use ssh vagrant vm from another vm running in same machine. If so, how to do that?

Comment: can you clarify _use ssh vagrant vm from another vm running in same machine_ ?

Comment: It mean that am running two vms A and B hosted in same machine. I want to connect to machine A from machine B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vagrant has a few options (see full doc https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html) :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.username = "user"
  config.ssh.password = "password"
end
```

**note** indeed, you need to make sure those users exist on the guest os (generally most vagrant box are created with vagrant user)

To have the connection between your different VMs, you can easily do that if you assign fix IP to the VM.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.45.15"
end
```

when you connect to your second VM, you can run `ssh vagrant@192.168.45.15` and it will ssh to the first VM